# Reverse Engineering Bluetooth led strips unsuccessful

Tags: bluetooth, smart-devices

duplicate of [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/homeautomation/comments/hnnr5t/how_to_reverse_engineer_led_light_strips/), and a few other kinda but nothing in any have solved my issue

I've got some [phopollo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N1HX72G) bluetooth led strips that I was trying reverse engineer the bluetooth protocol for so I could control them from python code and whatnot. I've successfully captured the color change packet using btsnoop_hci from an android phone and the official Apollo lighting app and put that into wireshark to find out the color change packet is 0207000e000a00040012090056ff000000f0aa Where everything up to ff0000 (the color in rgb values 0-255) is the same followed by 00f0aa which is always the same.  Except for the second btye "07" which I have no idea what does. It changes everytime you disconnect and reconnect to the device but doesn't change in-between. it seems to only be 01-09? because so far its been 07, 05 and 02. Wireshark says its the broadcast flag but I couldn't find too much information deeper online.

Anyway I used gattool to connect to the led strips and used char-write-cmd and char-write-req to try and write the packet to handel 0x0009 which is what wireshark says it is, I tried this with every number for the second byte 00-09 but nothing changed the color of the leds. It wrote the value but nothing happened. I tried doing the same thing with the nRF connect app on my iphone and it also didn't do anything. I also tried with another byte that I thought could have been on or off but nothing there or with any other bytes I tried.